# Custom sorting based on the content of an external array with Scala/Java API

Tags: java, scala, sorting, apache-spark

I have following data:-

```
+-------------+
|    card type|
+-------------+
|ColonialVoice|
| SuperiorCard|
|        Vista|
|  Distinguish|
+-------------+
```

I am having an array of custom order, I want dataset to be ordered as given in an array.

```
[ "Distinguish", "Vista", "ColonialVoice", "SuperiorCard"]
```

Expected output as following :-

```
+-------------+
|    card type|
+-------------+
|  Distinguish|
|        Vista|
|ColonialVoice|
| SuperiorCard|
+-------------+
```

How to achieve above custom sorting with spark Java API. 
Can anyone help for above using any API.

Comment: So the array has the same content as your dataframe or you just showed one column of the dataframe?

Comment: Also how big is that array?

Comment: Yes, array has same content as the column on which sorting will be applied where as there are some other colunms too.

Comment: But once this gets resolved i can sort other columns as I want.

Comment: Hello @vvp, did you check the solution below? I think it should work exactly as you described

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I have not tried your solution. I have found another way for this.

Comment: I will update my answer soon

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution, assuming you have a good reason for wanting to do this:

1. create a `DataFrame` from that array
2. add a column of `monotonically_increasing_id` to that `DataFrame`
3. join this `DataFrame` to your original `DataFrame` on the `card type` column
4. order by the `monotonically_increasing_id` column
5. drop the `monotonically_increasing_id` column

In Scala that would be:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id

val spark = ...
val df = ...
val order = Array("Distinguish", "Vista", "ColonialVoice", "SuperiorCard")
import spark.implicits._

val orderDF = order.toSeq.toDF
val orderDFWithId = orderDF.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
val joined = df.join(orderDFWithId, Seq("card type"), "left_outer")
val sortedDF = joined.orderBy("id").drop("id")
```

Comment: This will affect the performance because, there could be more columns to sort with different sorting options link asc, desc or custom sort as mentioned in question.

Comment: Of course it will affect performance. I would say that sorting is not a very good idea anyway in a distributed setting.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but requirement of feature on which I am working. Is there any other way to achieve because with partitioning I will face more difficulty with above approach

Comment: I think this approach is a good as you're going to get. If you broadcast the small orderDF (spark will probably do this automatically) then it's pretty low cost. You could alternatively write a UDF to generate the sort column.

Comment: Alternatively you could create the `id` (or whatever you want to call it) column before converting to a `DataFrame` (`zipWithIndex` comes to mind), but I don't know if that would really make a difference. You'll always have to do some sort of joining. Either explicitly like here, or by using a `udf` like in the other answer. You'd have to benchmark to know which way is more efficient (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which extracts the desired array index from the `card type` and then assign it into a new column. We can achieve that by utilizing Spark functions `array` and `array_position` introduced in Spark 2.4:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_position, array, udf, lit}
val cardTypes = Seq("Distinguish", "Vista", "ColonialVoice", "SuperiorCard")

val df = Seq(
("ColonialVoice"),
("SuperiorCard"),
("Vista"),
("Distinguish"))
.toDF("card_type")

df.withColumn("card_indx", 
              array_position(array(cardTypes.map(t => lit(t)):_*), $"card_type"))
              .orderBy("card_indx")
              .drop("card_indx")
              .show

// +-------------+
// |    card_type|
// +-------------+
// |  Distinguish|
// |        Vista|
// |ColonialVoice|
// | SuperiorCard|
// +-------------+
```

First we create an array from content of cardType Seq with `array(cardTypes.map(t => lit(t)):_*)` then extract and assign the index of the current card_type into a new column card_indx. Finally we order by card_indx.

For Spark < 2.4.0 array_position is not available and you can use an udf:

```
val getTypesIndx = udf((types: Seq[String], cardt: String) => cardTypes.indexOf(cardt))

df.withColumn("card_indx", getTypesIndx(array(cardTypes.map(t => lit(t)):_*), $"card_type"))
              .orderBy("card_indx")
              .drop("card_indx")
              .show
```